# Google chrome os and nativeclient code

Tags: google-nativeclient, google-chrome-os

In Chrome it is possible to write native code and have it run in the browser using the Native Client SDK.  Is it possible to do this in ChromeOS?  And is it possible to create a TCP or UDP binary socket in native client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it in ChromeOS - last time I've saw this bug: http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=1883 it is not fixed.

As for TCP/UDP - If you wish fast full duplex protocol you may use web sockets (with or without nacl).